# Replacing one column in a file with other values

Tags: python, file

I have a file like this:

```
1  0
1  0
1  0
2  0
2  0
2  0
3  0
3  0
3  0
3  0 
3  0
4  0
5  0
```

and another file, `file2` with one column:

```
0.122
0.133
0.855
-2.1
-9.00
```

I want to replace the second column of file one with data from `file2` such that the output file becomes this:

```
1  0.122
1  0.122
1  0.122
2  0.133
2  0.133
2  0.133
3  0.855
3  0.855
3  0.855
3  0.855
3  0.855
4  -2.1
5  -9
```

In other words, I want to copy the data from second file to first until the first column value remains same. when the value in first column changes, it picks a second value from the other file.

I have been trying it in python and have been able to replace the column but not meet the repetitions the desired number of times. my code just copies the data into first 5 positions of column2 in first file and leaves the rest. Can someone suggest a solution please?

Comment: file2 has the same count of rows as unique values in file1?

Comment: Show your current code

Comment: Yes, it has same count of rows but not repititions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to see your code but this might help you get your logic tweaked (it doesn't write to the original file and it assumes that the second file has enough lines):

```
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')

oldF1Value = None
v = None

for l1 in f1:
    [c1, c2] = l1.split()
    if (oldF1Value != c1):
        oldF1Value = c1
        v = f2.readline().splitlines()[0]

    print(c1, v)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your data from `file2` into a `dict` enumerating the lines.  Then read in the lines from `file1` and write to third file, `file3`, to keep both your original files unaltered.

```
with open('file2.txt') as file2:
    file2_data = dict(enumerate(file2.readlines(), 1))
    with open('file1.txt') as file1:
        file1_data = file1.readlines()
    with open('file3.txt', 'w') as file3:
        for line in file1_data:
            line_no = int(line.split()[0])
            file3.write('{} {}'.format(line_no, file2_data[line_no]))
```

Now `file3` will have the following:

```
1 0.122
1 0.122
1 0.122
2 0.133
2 0.133
2 0.133
3 0.855
3 0.855
3 0.855
3 0.855
3 0.855
4 -2.1
5 -9.00
```

There is also the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#fileinput) module, the code below will also create the same output as above:

```
import fileinput


with open('data2.txt') as f2:
    f2_raw = [i.strip('\n') for i in f2.readlines()]
    f2 = dict(enumerate(f2_raw, 1))
    for line in fileinput.input('data1.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
        line_no = int(line.split()[0])
        print(line_no, f2[line_no])
```